# Why is exponential fit always worse than guess

Tags: python, scipy

I have a set of samples that follow an exponential distribution. I want to fit an exponential function to the [ECDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function). I am using scipy's `curve_fit` for this, but it always produces a fit that is worse than the trivial guess. Why?

Working example:

```py
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import expon
import plotly.graph_objects as go

samples = numpy.random.exponential(size=111, scale=11)

cdf_model = lambda x, scale: expon.cdf(x,loc=0,scale=scale)

scale_guess = 1/(len(samples)/sum(samples))

samples_sorted = numpy.sort(samples)
samples_ecdf = numpy.arange(1, len(samples_sorted)+1)/float(len(samples_sorted))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(
    f = cdf_model,
    xdata = samples,
    ydata = samples_ecdf,
    p0 = scale_guess,
)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = samples_sorted,
        y = samples_ecdf,
        name = 'ECDF',
        line_shape='hv',
    )
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = samples_sorted,
        y = cdf_model(samples_sorted, *popt),
        name = 'Fit',
    )
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = samples_sorted,
        y = cdf_model(samples_sorted, scale_guess),
        name = 'guess',
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a statistically valid way to fit the ECDF.  The problem is that the fitting procedure assumes the deviations between the points and the fit behave like *independent* random errors--but you can see, even on this plot, that the deviations are strongly correlated.  A far simpler and appropriate method is to estimate the exponential parameter from the data, which *are* independent.  The maximum likelihood estimate equals your guess!  In other words, **your guess is the best fit.**

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Actually I know that my guess is the MLE, but I have some distributions that are a bit noisy and I want to check if the simple exponential fit may be more robust as I don't want to change the model.

Comment: The MLE will be better for the reasons I gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to replace `samples` with `samples_sorted` in `curve_fit`:

```py
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import expon

samples = numpy.random.exponential(size=111, scale=11)

cdf_model = lambda x, scale: expon.cdf(x,loc=0,scale=scale)

scale_guess = 1/(len(samples)/sum(samples))

samples_sorted = numpy.sort(samples)
samples_ecdf = numpy.arange(1, len(samples_sorted)+1)/float(len(samples_sorted))
popt, _ = curve_fit(
    f = cdf_model,
    xdata = samples_sorted,
    ydata = samples_ecdf,
    p0 = scale_guess,
)

plt.plot(samples_sorted, samples_ecdf)
plt.plot(samples_sorted, cdf_model(samples_sorted, *popt), c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Although this solves the *programming* issue, it is a statistically misleading answer: see my comment to the question.